# Creating an MSI from an exe and a configuration file

Tags: windows-installer

The MSI I want to create is for the well known [Sysmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) tool.

Sysmon can be installed using the following command : `Sysmon64.exe -i sysmonconfig.xml -accepteula` :

- `Sysmon64.exe` can be downloaded from the Microsoft [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon).
- `sysmonconfig.xml` is a configuration file, it is required for Sysmon installation.

I would like to create an MSI that wraps the components above and launches the installation command line. What is the simplest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the WiX toolset to create an MSI package that instead the files on a Component and calls the command line as a CustomAction.